# Do weapon stats only apply when the weapon is active?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For example, I'm carrying an axe with 20% damage bonus. Does that only apply to the axe when it is active, or also to the flame thrower, my primary weapon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally weapon stats only apply when the weapon is active, however there are a few exceptions to this, the [pain train](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Pain_Train) being just one example. The wearer gets both of the weapons benefits regardless of whether or not the weapon is active:

[image]

Weapons effects which take place without the weapon being active will be followed with "on wearer", like in the above example. These effects will also appear under the  "Current on-wearer attributes" header on the character load out page:

[image]

Comment: Also, in the loadout screen, on-wearer effects will be listed below the image of your character. (Feel free to edit this in, or not)

Answer (score 1):

Damage increases/decreases are usually weapon-specific, meaning the buff/debuff only applies while that particular weapon is active. Other attributes, such as fire or explosive vulnerability, apply to the character as a whole no matter what the active weapon is.